# what is the actual image name/path in this css

Tags: css, base64

I was dealing with a website, the site has a copy image button. when i saw the source code of css to find the path/ png name of that image, i saw the below css. Can any one inform me where/what is the path/ name of the image here ? How to get form this encrypted data ?

```
.copy_png{
background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) top left no-repeat;);
height:25px;
width:25px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is a Base64 encoded image, but you can still get to it and save it as you like.

In Chrome's console, simply open an about:blank, then create an img element and assign the data:image.png, base64, ... data as its' source. Then append to the body. You'll see your image which you can then right-click and save-as.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Here's your image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This image has no (external) path or name. The image itself is base64 encoded in the url. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397 for the specification.